# Is it possible for a script to change the foreground color while using brush tool in Photoshop?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

Lately I've been playing with Photoshop and javascript and I managed to do many tasks like conditional resizing etc.

Now I'm probably too ambitious, but I'd like to make a script that constantly changes the foreground color while painting with the brush tool. Basically the result could be a gradient from color A to color B painted in a single brush stroke.

The first question is: does Photoshop allow this? I'm not sure it will accept a change in the foreground color while the brush tool is being used.

If the answer to question #1 is yes, then the next question is: how should I approach this?
I guess the script would need to be looping (maybe something like in Processing language?), and then the user should be able to start or stop the loop at a given time.

Thanks in advance to all those who'll spend their time here!

Comment: I haven't come across any functionality that would even come close to accomplishing this.  The best I have been able to stroke a pre-defined vector, but even then you wouldn't be able to change color in a nice gradient - you're reliant on the typical color jitter settings.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting. Alright, I'll have to find something else to play with! Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in engine by locking color-dynamics to pen pressure for foreground/background jitter in the brush palette then using something like LazyNezumi to send a command to the channel based on software rules. Its pretty much the only way to do it while a stroke is live as foreground changes only occur after a stroke is completed.

I've got a brush set up to do it on pressure I call 'What it feels like to chew 5gum' and depending on the pressure config on your wacom, you can get lots of really interesting effects and swapping foreground/background is especially helpful. Its really useful when the colors involved are only slightly different but also super fun when you make them wildly different (cerise + cyan for example).